# Get Memory-RAM information consumed by an app using shell command

Tags: android, linux, unix, awk, android-profiler

I just want to get RAM information consumed by a specific app using shell command, currently i as using **ps -x | grep 'packageName'** but its results vary with the memory shown by profiler

This is the result of the above command that i am using

u0_a73    7623  4287  3271364 **225728** SyS_epoll_ 73289f334c S packageName (u:193963, s:87819)

The bold part is the ram consumed by the app in kB

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ps -x|awk '/packageName/{print $5}'
```

The `awk` command extract the 5th word from the `ps -x` output having packageName in the line.

Comment: but why it varies with the memory shown in profiler ?

Comment: The solution assumes the memory is the fifth field/word. If cannot guaranty the memory field position. call ps or other command to get a persistent output format.